# Python Error - Detected at node 'mean_squared_error/Cast'

Tags: python, dataframe, keras, kaggle, sequential

**I am trying to fit model for following dataframe.**

> ssdf.columns =  array(['category', 'age', 'gender', 'height',
> 'weight', 'attitude.roll',
> 'attitude.pitch', 'attitude.yaw', 'gravity.x', 'gravity.y',
> 'gravity.z', 'rotationRate.x', 'rotationRate.y', 'rotationRate.z',
> 'userAcceleration.x', 'userAcceleration.y', 'userAcceleration.z'],
> dtype=object)

[image]

**Python Code:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = ssdf.loc[:, columns]
y = ssdf.loc[:,['category']]
#y = ssdf.loc[:,['gravity.x']]

xn, xt, yn, yt = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=101)

n_features = 1
#series = series.reshape((len(X), n_features))
# define generator
n_input = 20
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(xn.values, yn.values, length=n_input, batch_size=1)
# print each sample
#for i in range(len(generator)):
#    x, y = generator[i]
#    print('%s => %s' % (x, y))
    
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=500, verbose=0)
```

**I am getting following error:** in Kaggle Notebook

> UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[28], line 29
> 26 model.add(Dense(2))
> 27 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
> ---> 29 model.fit(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=500, verbose=0)
>
> File
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70,
> in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> 68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
> 69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
> ---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 71 finally:
> 72     del filtered_tb
>
> File
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52,
> in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
> 50 try:
> 51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
> ---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> 53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
> 54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 55   if name is not None:
>
> UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:
>
> Detected at node 'mean_squared_error/Cast' defined at (most recent
> call last):
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line
> 17, in 
> app.launch_new_instance()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 1043, in launch_instance
> app.start()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line
> 728, in start
> self.io_loop.start()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py",
> line 195, in start
> self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
> self._run_once()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
> handle._run()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
> self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
> line 513, in dispatch_queue
> await self.process_one()
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
> line 502, in process_one
> await dispatch(*args)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
> line 409, in dispatch_shell
> await result
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py",
> line 729, in execute_request
> reply_content = await reply_content
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line
> 422, in do_execute
> res = shell.run_cell(
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line
> 540, in run_cell
> return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3009, in run_cell
> result = self._run_cell(
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3064, in _run_cell
> result = runner(coro)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py",
> line 129, in *pseudo_sync_runner
> coro.send(None)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3269, in run_cell_async
> has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3448, in run_ast_nodes
> if await self.run_code(code, result, async*=asy):
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3508, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
> File "/tmp/ipykernel_32/1342990786.py", line 29, in 
> model.fit(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=500, verbose=0)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
> line 65, in error_handler
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1685, in fit
> tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1284, in train_function
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1268, in step_function
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1249, in run_step
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1051, in train_step
> loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 1109, in compute_loss
> return self.compiled_loss(
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py",
> line 265, in **call**
> loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in **call**
> losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call
> return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1469, in mean_squared_error
> y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype) Node: 'mean_squared_error/Cast' Cast string to float is not supported
> [[{{node mean_squared_error/Cast}}]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_24923]

**What am I doing wrong?**